# How to use ROW_NUMBER to order date?

Tags: bigdata

I want to order the date in ascending.
I've tried

```sql
select
PARSE_DATE('%A, %B %d, %Y',date) AS Scraping_Date,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by date asc) as row_num
FROM `kramplab-analytics-rnd.kramplab_shared_dwh.LAB_FR_2023-07_google_shopping_full_detail`
group by scraping_date, date
```

The result was

[image: result]

but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

I want to parse the date and order the date in ascending and pick the oldest date.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking

Comment: I think you can add  "order by Scraping_Date" in sql .